# Code push is showing memory leak in the react native app

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am using code push for my app but it is showing me memory leak

```
useEffect(() => {
    checkforupdate();
  }, []);

  async function checkforupdate() {
    codePush.sync(
      {
        installMode: codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESTART,
      },
      checkdata,
    );
  }
  function checkdata(syncStatus) {
    switch (syncStatus) {
      case codePush.SyncStatus.CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE:
        break;
      case codePush.SyncStatus.DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE:
        break;
      case codePush.SyncStatus.AWAITING_USER_ACTION:
        break;
      case codePush.SyncStatus.INSTALLING_UPDATE:
        break;
      case codePush.SyncStatus.UP_TO_DATE:
        break;
      case codePush.SyncStatus.UPDATE_IGNORED:
        break;
      case codePush.SyncStatus.UPDATE_INSTALLED:
        break;
      case codePush.SyncStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        break;
      default:
        null;
    }
  }s
```

what is the issue in this i am not able to get it. As i have checked with all functions but it is giving me memory leak on app start. In this checkdata() is calling 2 times i think i don't know why and i think so that my other function is call again.

Error:
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function